# How can I prevent my terminal from breaking?

Tags: shell, docker, kubernetes, watch

I am using a `watch` command(in a shell script) in my docker image.

Command:

```
watch -d -t -g ls -la  ${DIR_TO_WATCH} && sleep 5  && ${COMMAND} | tee
```

This command is watching a directory and if there is any change in the directory structure, we perform certain actions.

I am using this docker image in my helm chart.
Now, when I deploy the chart and check the logs of that pod, my terminal breaks and it will not be user friendly anymore.

Command:

```
kubectl logs -f pod-name -n name-space
```

After this, we need to reset terminal settings to get the terminal behave normal.

Is there anything that can be done to prevent this?

Best Regards,
Akshat

Comment: Can you clarify distribution ? there are multiple watch programs

Comment: Question isn't about writing code anyhow. May be on-topic on [unix.se], but it isn't here.

Comment: BTW, read [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) about the use of `${COMMAND}`. Arrays, not strings, should be used to store argument lists for later execution.

Comment: @dash-o I am using centos 7.7 and watch from procps-ng 3.3.10.

Comment: Also, I found [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236009/how-to-wrap-output-of-watch-command) where they have talked about using "fold -s" along with watch. Could this be of any use here?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes are you using?

Comment: @DawidKruk I am using v1.15.4.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `${COMMAND}` in `watch -d -t -g ls -la  ${DIR_TO_WATCH} && sleep 5  && ${COMMAND} | tee` holds an EVN variable value which is a shell script file path(ex: /etc/elasticsearch/auth/sgadmin.sh). 
Do you think this might have caused the broken terminal?

Comment: No. Doing that with a simple filename with no spaces, quotes or glob characters is still not good practice, but it won't cause the problems BashFAQ #50 is about (and those problems will lead to the command misbehaving, but not generally a broken terminal).

Comment: First place I'd look is for terminal control sequences in your log file. Pipe the log to less, and with out-of-the-box configuration it should sanitize its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by sending output of `watch` to `/dev/null`.

`watch -d -t -g ls -la  ${DIR_TO_WATCH} > /dev/null && sleep 5  && ${COMMAND} | tee`

The reason, according to my understanding, behind broken terminal was:

Two different command's logs(logs from `watch` and `${COMMAND}`) were showing up on the same terminal at the same time, which resulted in creating a new terminal over the default one(which I am not sure how), causing the default terminal to break.

While `${COMMAND}` logs were crucial for me, I did not need to view or monitor logs from `watch`. Hence, I sent the log outputs of `watch` to `/dev/null` and it solved my problem.

Please correct me if my understanding or approach is wrong.

Thank you.